# access denied to access to /etc/hosts

Tags: java, filesystems, bufferedwriter

i can't access to hosts file of windows with java (just write) :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts (Access is denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
```

when i want append my text to hosts file get above error ...

this is my code :

```
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        // APPEND MODE SET HERE
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));
        bw.write(text);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.flush();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {                       try {
        // always close the file
        bw.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileWrite.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } 

} // end test()
```

this code work for simple files in other location of windows .. (just get error on c:\windows\ ...

and : 
i use microsoft manifest to set administration access [not work]

set full access to hosts file [not work]

please help ..

tnx

Comment: Run your java app as administrator

Comment: For "microsoft manifest administrative privileges" you need an exe file, but you can run cmd as administrator, and then use the java command to start your app.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your java is really running as administrator (i.e. write to a new file in the same folder). There is obviously access problem and to solve it you need to understand who you are (user/service of your app) and what are permissions of resource (file) you are trying to access.

here are two ways how you can try and debug it:
1) You don't have permissions to write the file (can you read it?)
2) You don't have permissions to enter the folder (can you list files in it)

Comment: it's work for other drives , just access denied on C:\\Windows\\
i test my code on other files and works

Comment: If the permission scheme is different it will work, you have to determine what does it look like in the place where it does not work.